# Function describing trajectory of a point on a rolling circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, implicit-function

Let us take a 2D unit circle $C$ with center in $M=(0,1)$ and fix a point on $C$, say $A=(0,0)$. Now we start to unroll the circle to the right and watch how $A$ moves; firstly, it turns around $M$ on the perimeter of $C$ clockwise; secondly, it moves to the right exactly about the length of the arc that has already been unrolled.

The trajectory of $A$ can be described as
$$
Tr(A)=\{(\alpha-\sin\alpha,1-\cos\alpha):\alpha\in[0,2\pi]\}
$$
(which looks a bit like the upper half of an ellipse).

Now the question occurs, **how $Tr(A)$ can be described explicitly by the graph of a function**. Therefore I would try to solve
$$
x=\alpha-\sin\alpha
$$
for $\alpha$, which, to me, already seems hopeless. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you had a look at [Cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid)?

Comment: Thanks, this one word should already answer my question -.-

Answer (score 1):

As you already found out from the comment above, the curve you're describing is a cycloid. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) on the subject gives an equation of the form $x=f(y)$ for half of the "hump", but says (without any proof) that an equation of the form $y=f(x)$ is not possible.